# This problem of probability

Tags: probability

*If every time I go out I have 1% of chance of finding a coin of the street, if I go out 100 times, what are the chances that I will find at least 1 coin on the street?*

At first glance I thought that I would have to sum the chances of finding a coin every time I go out, but that would be 100%, which I know isn't corret, so how do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Turn it around: what is the chance that you **fail** to find a coin $100$ times in a row?

Comment: is it 0,99^100?

Comment: @Dhiego: That’s the probability of $100$ failures, yes. So the probability of at least one success is ... ?

Comment: 1 - 0,99^100. Good way to think. I wonder that would be much harder without thinking the oposite.

Comment: @Dhiego: That’s right. You’ll find that it’s often much easier to calculate the probability of the complementary (opposite) event and subtract from $1$.